# Diagram with axes $r$ and $S,I$

Tags: interest-rate, investment, saving

In the figure below, I have a coordinate system where $r$ depends on $I$ or $S$, but I do not completely understand why I can have multiple functions inside this coordinate system.

Why can I write $S(r)$ and $I(r)$? Normally, in an x-y-diagram, I interpret it as $y(x)$, since $x$ varies and $y$ depends on $x$.

The diagram below is a quite normal diagram in economics, so I know it is correct, but why isn't the figure 'transposed', i.e. with $r$ on the $x$-axis and $S,I$ on the $y$-axis?

It doesn't make sense that $r = S(r)$ or $r = I(r)$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It was **Alfred Marshall's doing**, but based on a premise that still prevails in many parts of Economics: if prices are assumed totally elastic, then, although it may be the case that they are taken as given by the individual buyers or sellers, at ***market*** level ***it is quantity that determines price***. So price is indeed the dependent variable, if you care about the market and not about the individual.

And here is page 96 from Marshall's [**Principles of Economics (8th ed.1920),**](http://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/1676) (the 1st edition was in 1890), the funny thing being that here Marshall talks about... individual demand! (but it would be totally confusing to swap axes between graphing individual demand and graphing market demand). Read the annotated footnote.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is very counter-intuitive and confusing. However, there is an interesting explanation involving graphical analysis of demand and supply i.e. [why swap axes?](http://blog.jparsons.net/2011/02/why-do-economists-put-price-on-vertical.html) . I think, the explanation in that link may offer you some elements of answer.

Comment: You provided a very good link. Perhaps you could include some of its content into the body of your answer?

Comment: Okay, next time then.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes economists are bad at drawing graphs.

For example, think of a supply and demand graph. Price is on the y axis and quantity is on the x axis, but generally when we derive the curves for competitive markets, we usually say that firms and consumers respond to price to determine what quantity they buy/sell, rather than the other way around. So why aren't the axes switched there so the dependent and independent variables are where they should be? Tradition I guess.

I imagine it's a similar case here. The axes are just wonky.